# Generate distinct values from a column in a spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-collections

I have a spark dataframe like below

```
id|name|age|sub
1 |ravi|21 |[M,J,J,K]
```

I don't want to explode on the column "sub" as it will create another extra set of rows. I want generate unique values from the "sub" column and assign it to new column sub_unique.

My output should be like

```
id|name|age|sub_unique
1 |ravi|21 |[M,J,K]
```

Comment: is `sub` string column ? can add dataframe schema ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `udf`

```
val distinct = udf((x: Seq[String]) => if (s != null) x.distinct else Seq[String]())

df.withColumn("subm_unique", distinct($"sub"))
```

Comment: your solution did not work. I am getting below error while executing    "Flat hash tables cannot contain null elements"